# Protege inconsistent ontology ambiguous explanation

Tags: rdf, owl, protege

I have a class `Course` and a data property `courseCode` on the domain `Course` with range `xsd:string`.

I added an individual, a `Course` named "Databases". I also wanted to add the data property assertion `courceCode` with a value of "DAT475" and a type of `xsd:string`. But after doing that I get this error:

[image: inconsistent ontology explanation]

What does this mean? What did I do wrong?

Edit: The file I'm working on is using turtle syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a plain literal (the presence of an `@en` language tag separates a plain literal from a string literal) as filler for a property whose range is defined as xsd:string (i.e., limited to string literals only).

It's a bit counterintuitive, but the problem is that plain string literals and strings are not in the same datatype.

Comment: in RDF this datatype by the way would be `rdf:langString` which indeed you know but isn't part of OWL nor Protege. Cheers

Comment: I opened the equivalent of the same file, but in rdf/xml syntax, did the same steps, and now it works!? But now instead of saying `@en` next to it in the data property assertions, it says `^^xsd:string`. Is there any difference in protege when opening the "same" file with different syntax?

Comment: In fact, the problem is that *language tagged plain literals* are not plain strings. Plain literals with no language tag **are** plain strings. Different literals can have different datatypes and yet be the same value, e.g., ``"2.0"^^xsd:decimal`` and ``"2"^^xsd:int``.

Comment: @Nermin, if you have ``xsd:string`` now instead of ``@en`` it means that you did not use an equivalent file. RDF/XML encodes the language tag in an ``xml:lang`` attribute. It must have been omitted.